# How to store archived copies of a WordPress site

Tags: pages, archives

Has anyone implemented a site archival capability that saves copies of what an entire wordpress site looked like at various past dates in times?

I am looking for any plugins or codex development methods that allows me to save copies of my wordpress "Pages" as they existed at points in time in the past and the (somehow) be able to query the site and show what it looked like on, say, June 5, 2015.

Is that possible to do?

I am not looking for Post archives...that already exists. I am looking for Page archiving.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One option: revisions. If you save a large number of revisions for your pages, you can then browse through the revision history and "Preview" what a particular page looked like at a particular point in time. However, this requires whoever is viewing the past view to be logged in, since Previews are not public.

Another option: you can manually save pages one at a time by telling the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/) to index a particular page immediately. To capture a snapshot, you can paste the URL into that site (where it says Save Page Now) and later return to view it at any time. If you're working on a better-linked-to site, you may find that they already have some snapshots of some of your content.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin - [Blog to HTM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-to-html/)L - that exports all posts (only) to an HTML file. No formatting, although class codes are put on all basic content elements.  It does not export pages, or sidebars/widget content, but it does include any images associated with the post as well as galleries. It will export all categories, or you can export specific categories.

I use it as a start for a conversion of a blog to an ebook.

Since it is in the plugin repository, it is open source, so you could use the code therein to create your own export of just pages.